# String not getting printed

Tags: c, printf, puts

I have been trying to solve a problem, Everything works fine, except that the required string is not getting printed

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int test,i,number,num1;

char ch;
scanf("%d",&test);
for(i=test;i>0;i--)
{
    scanf("%d",&number);

    num1=number;

    while(num1>12)
    {
        num1-=12;
    }

    if(num1>0 && num1<7)
    printf("%d ",(2*(6-num1)+1)+number);


    else
    printf("%d ",number-(2*(num1-7)+1));


    if(num1==(1 || 6 || 12 || 7 ))
    {
        puts("WS");
    }

    if(num1==(2|| 5 || 8 || 11))
    {
        puts("MS");
    }

    if(num1==(3 || 4 || 9 || 10))
    { 
       puts("AS");
    }
    }


return 0;
}
```

Here along with a numeric value, corresponding AS, WS or MS is required to be printed, but after printing the numeric value, the code just ends there, I've also tried other things but none of those worked. Other things which I tried are:
1) Used a character array to store AS, WS or MS and then printing with printf.
2)Used just a character and stored just A, W or M in it and print them along with S already present in the printf function. In this method, S was getting printed but A, W or M wasn't.

Comment: That's not how the logical OR works. You need to split up your comparisons.

Comment: regarding this kind of statement: ` if(num1==(1 || 6 || 12 || 7 ))`  it should be: `if( num1 == 1 || num1 == 6 || num1 == 12 ||  num1 == 7 )`  Your compiler should have told you about this problem.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to perform the same things

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every (even omitted optional) opening braces '{'. Unindent before every (even omitted optional) closing braces '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont't think that you have a problem with puts or printf. I think you just have to write your if or clauses as

```
if(num1==1 || num1==6 || num1==12 || num1==7 )
```

rather than.

```
if(num1==(1 || 6 || 12 || 7 ))
```

See eg. [logical or](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_logical)

Comment: thanks, man it worked. I never knew that I was focusing on the wrong part of my code.

Answer (score 0):

I think `switch case` loop better suits your need:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int test,i,number,num1;

char ch;
scanf("%d",&test);
for(i=test;i>0;i--)
{
    scanf("%d",&number);

    num1=number;

    while(num1>12) num1-=12;


    if(num1>0 && num1<7)
    printf("%d ",(2*(6-num1)+1)+number);


    else
    printf("%d ",number-(2*(num1-7)+1));


    switch(num1){
        case 1:
        case 6:
        case 12:
        case 7:
            puts("WS");
            break;
        case 2:
        case 5:
        case 8:
        case 11:
            puts("MS");
            break;
        default:
            puts("AS");
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I was ignoring switch cases because I wanted to use logical or and honestly, I never knew, we use switch cases in this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(num1==(1 || 6 || 12 || 7 ))
```

when the compiler sees this if condition it will check if num1 is equal to the result of (1 || 6 || 12|| 7) which is 1 since all values are true(1) looking from boolean perspective(not 0). So the program will execute the code under all 3 if conditions which prints characters, only when num1 is equal to 1.

the solution is as follows:

```
if(num1==1 || num1 == 6 || num1 == 12 || num1 == 7)
```